# Parsing setting from JSON object lead to string is not a function

Tags: javascript, json

So I have this JSON object given for my project. It contain multiple settings, some of them are strings some are booleans.

However I am unable to perform one thing, which is adding animation name from the object stored in variable.

```
aniFx.move(inner, {
    duration: 1,
    delta: aniFx.ease.bouncePast
});
```

**Explanation**

```
Inner: document.getElementById('inner');
Duration: time multiplied by 1000 in my animation script (aniFx)
Delta: Animation used for moving the inner element
```

So now that I explained, that is working perfectly fine, until I try to set `delta` from JSON object.
Let's say for sake of this question that my JSON object contains only following:

```
_userObj = JSON.parse('{ "137340": { "effect": "aniFx.ease.swingTo" } }');
```

---

Now, why I am unable to do this for example:

```
aniFx.move(inner, {
    duration: 1,
    delta: _userObj['137340'].effect
});
```

I will get following error when I trigger the function...

**Console will return:**

```
console.log => aniFx.ease.swingTo
aniFx.move => Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

Comment: `"anifx.ease.swingTo"` is a string. It won't automatically be evaluated as an expression.

Comment: @Barmar, is there any way I can resolve this and make it a function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot package functions as JSON.

```
_userObj['137340'].effect
```

evaluates to just a string ("aniFx.ease.swingTo") that you try to pass as delta, which is then tried to be called as function when executing aniFx.move.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this ? Nothing on my mind.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/1744702) could work. so you would pass this for the move function: window[_userObj['137340'].effect]

Comment: Unfortunately, not in my case :-/ !
_Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function_

Comment: That would only work if the value were a global variable, not an expression. You need to use `eval()`, with all the dangers it has.

Comment: Well, as it isn't global, if there are only handful of possible values for that, you could use switch structure to match the string and on match point to that function like this: case _"aniFx.ease.swingTo": effect = aniFx.ease.swingTo;_ and then pass the effect for move function.

Comment: @Barmar - I tried `eval()` it works, but I'll rather skip using it.
@Sanfor - Yeh I guess I could do that then... Thank you!